# I wish to create a drop down select list with option items that can trigger http Get and refresh the page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I wish to create a drop down select list with option items that can trigger http Get and refresh the page.
I wish to run some code in the controller action when an option in the drop down is clicked.
I used the Html.DropdownlistFor() helper but I could not manipulate it thus.
Here is the code so you can understand me better,

```
var olist = db.ItemPackagingUnits.Where(i => i.ItemName.Equals(item.ItemName.ToUpper().Trim()));
       <td>
         <select>
               @foreach(var oitem in olist)
               { 
                  <option value ='<a href ="/Restaurant/DoSales?ItemName=@item.ItemName&PackagingUnit=@oitem.UnitOfMeasurementName&recalulatePrice=true">@oitem.UnitOfMeasurementName</a>'>@oitem.UnitOfMeasurementName</option>
               }
         </select>
      </td>
```

I hope I have given enough information on what I wish to achieve. DoSales is an action in the Restaurant Controller which has both Get and Post parts but I only wish to call the get part and refresh the page at the same time (or else I would have used Ajax or JSon) when the user clicks on any of the options in the drop down that was generated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that with the `DropDownListFor()` HTML helper. Instead of embedded HTML in the `value` attribute, take out the anchor TAG (`<a>`) code, leave the URL you're generating, and use JavaScript to bind to the `change` event of the generated `select` element (Drop-down list). Then you can use JavaScript to figure out which element was selected and write `window.location = myDropdown.options[myDropdown.selectedIndex].value;`. There are other ways to improve this but the general idea is for the OPTION tag to contain just what you need and combine your work with JS to handle the redirect

Comment: Use Jquery to bind the select list change event and fire an ajax request based off the value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked! Thanks Mario J Vargas! Here are the code and javascript!

```
var olist = db.ItemPackagingUnits.Where(i => i.ItemName.Equals(item.ItemName.ToUpper().Trim()));
   <td>
     <select onchange ="myFunc(this)">
           @foreach(var oitem in olist)
           { 
              <option value ='/Restaurant/DoSales?ItemName=@item.ItemName&PackagingUnit=@oitem.UnitOfMeasurementName&recalulatePrice=true'>@oitem.UnitOfMeasurementName</option>
           }
     </select>
  </td> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(myDropdown) {
        //var myDropdown = document.getElementById(ddname);
        window.location = myDropdown.options[myDropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Anon, your suggestion I believe has some merit and sounds feasible but I quickly implemented Mario's. Thanks for responding though. Indeed, there ain't no place like StackOverflow! Thanks again, Mario and Anon.